# Columns on bootstrap not in the same row

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I have a weird problem. I have the following html code[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BIYT.png), but, the idea is that panelPrincipal starts hidden with the following code at js:

```
var panelPrincipal = document.getElementById('panelPrincipal');
panelPrincipal.style.display="none";
```

Once I have chose the main character with the panelSelecProta, a funtion change the style.display="none" to style.display="block". The thing is, I tested the panelPrincipal and it worked fine [Correct position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1u5u.png), but, when I set the display to block, the columns appears under the other.
[bad position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u289T.png)

I try to find where it fails, but I only find that the setting of display at function is what make it to fail, but I don't know why

Comment: Please don't post code as an image and instead post the code itself (as text) in your question.

Comment: Just check the [Display Property Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) to learn how each value (like `block`) behaves.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@DanielLykos because you are using block that's why it is breaking the column and show in rows instead use
**display:inline-block**

This will solve your problem